# Rails - Return additional attributes with object from controller using JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, attributes

This is the code in my People Controller for the Create action :

```
def create
  @person = Person.new(person_params)
  @person.branch_id = session[:branch_id]
  @person.added_by = current_user.id
  if @person.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @person}
    end
  end
end
```

And I have a method in my Person Model to get the person's full name :

```
def full_name
    [self.first_name, self.middle_name, self.last_name].reject(&:blank?).join(" ")
end
```

What is the best way to add the Person's full name to @person when it is returned back as a JSON object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you want it to be in the JSON you could just override the `as_json` method of the `Person` class to include the options to add the `full_name` method:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super options.merge(methods: [:full_name])
end
```

This method is used by Rails whenever an object should be serialized into a JSON string, for example by `render json: @person`. If you only want to add the extra method on this single occasion you can also call it directly inline using `render json: @person.as_json(methods: [:full_name])` or if you want to make more complex customizations to the JSON output you could think about using dedicated serializer classes, for example by using the [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) gem. However, as you only want to add one method and that probably everywhere you are serializing `@person`, the best way for your case would be to just override `as_json` as described in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article: 
http://www.tigraine.at/2011/11/17/rails-to_json-nested-includes-and-methods

It's got instructions for doing exactly what you're trying to do, the short story being that you need to pass in :my_method => full_name to the json rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

@person.as_json(methods: :full_name)